# Open in explorer view to show a filtered view of the list or library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, list-view, filter, open-with-explorer

I am looking at a filtered view of my library on my site so I am only seeing certain items. When I click open in explorer, I see everything in the library and my filter is no longer applied.

Is it possible for me to click open in explorer and see only that filtered view of my library not all 5000 items?

If so how can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not. Explorer opens up a connection to the library and you see everything that you can see based on your permissions (namely non-approvers not seeing drafts). The only way to filter it is to map that folder to a drive, search for whatever it is you want to filter by and then save that search in Explorer, but that won't be at the same level of functionality that you see with SharePoint library views.

Comment: That's interesting.. so would I be able to create a user that has permissions to certain documents (maybe based on a column value)? Because then I can just log in as this user and achieve the goal right?

Comment: No, permissions only limit users from being able to see documents if they're published (as opposed to draft copies). Column values don't get used in Explorer other than the Name, Title, dates and Author. If the values you want to search on are in that, you can filter a search and save it to be reused locally (the title for that depends on your OS version). 

Some tips on it <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/advanced-tips-for-searching-in-windows">here</a> if you're using Win7+. 

In browser is still your best bet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question because I was looking for a way to do the same thing. Luckily I discovered a workaround through a little guesswork. I've found that you can just filter the list of items from your library, select the files you need, then drag and drop the files where you'd like to place them. This method worked for me using SharePoint 2016.